# Обработка plist (xml ) для android или его аналог

Tags: java, android, ios, kotlin

В iOS  для хранения данных, которые мб использованы можно использовать .plist (по своей форме очень похожи на xml)

```
<array>
<string>Кличка собаки </string>
<string>Порода собаки </string> 
</array> 

<array>
<string>Кличка кошки </string>
<string>Цвет  </string> 
</array> 

</plist>
```

Я хочу, чтобы данные использовались в одном формате (для удобства) (или были очень похожи друг на друга)
Но я не знаю как извлечь массив данных на Android. Читала, что в iOS есть встроенные методы по работе с xml
(Делается все в 5 строк кода)
Как это сделать на Android? Желательно в Kotlin
Я предполагаю, что сначала нужно найти сам файл

'var nameOffile = File (pathname:"animals.xml") '
Далее записать содержимое в строку
На этом шаге сделать не получается, происходит краш программы.
И третий шаг извлечь общий массив из этой строки
Можно ли это осуществить? Или в android вообще нужен другой формат для хранения такого типа информации??

Comment: `по своей форме очень похожи на xml` - это и есть стандартный xml

Comment: можно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161256/referencing-a-string-in-a-string-array-resource-with-xml

Comment: Почему не использовать JSON?